How to setup webhook to Docusign external app?
I am working on an integration of Docusign with my app (external app). The integration will follow the envelope lifecycle and for this purpose I want to use a webhook (Connect) that will listen when the envelope status changes to completed.
Is there such a possibility that the external app will receive events from users who have consented to it or is it only for users in my account?

There's a feature called "Recipient Connect" which enables your app to receive events for other accounts.
Recipient Connect is a webhook service that pushes notifications to your app when an event that you’ve subscribed to occurs, just like DocuSign Connect. Recipient Connect differs from DocuSign Connect in that it provides event notifications when a specific domain user in your organization is a recipient (a signer or carbon copy recipient) of an envelope and a subscribed action occurs, rather than when they are a sender and the action occurs.
Prerequisites
Before you can use Recipient Connect:

You must have an organization
Your organization must have claimed a domain
claimed a domain, opens in new window. If your organization's plan enables it, you can claim a domain for free.
The account(s) that will receive envelopes and trigger Recipient Connect event notifications must be linked to your organization.

If you are not the sender or the recipient of the envelopes the above will not work
In that case you have to build something else. You have to dynamically create Connect Configurations on the accounts of your customers (require admin level access) and that way you can still use Connect without having it on your own account.
Note: I assume you will impersonate your customer's accounts/users using JWT for the above.

Hey Inbar thanks for the replay. I couldn't understand, in the first sentence you wrote that Recipient Connect allows me to receive events from other accounts, but later on in the message you treated it in such a way that the events are only related to the users who are in my organization (and there are actually the recipients and not the senders of the envelope).
So just to clarify - the events that interest me are related to users who are not in my organization at all, they are my clients and have their own Docusign account, is it still possible to listen to envelope events related to them?

ok, to clarify, if there are 2 accounts involved, sender and signer, and you as the ISV are not in either - you cannot do this.
Connect requires that you are either the sender or the receiver of the envelope to get events about them.
Since I saw some other questions by you, I know you're building an ISV integration where you won't be either. In that case what things like PowerAutomate etc. do is programmatically create a connect configuration in the account (require admin acesss) with a dynamic URL to their endpoint. Let me update my answer.
